# Populate Jquery Autocomplete With Images From Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use the following code **to populate jQuery autocomplete list from Google Spreadsheet to show username suggestions**:

**Autocomplete.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags" />
</div>

<script>
// This code in this function runs when the page is loaded.
$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildTagList)
      .getAvailableTags();
});

function buildTagList(availableTags) {
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
}
</script>
```

**getAvailableTags()**

```
function getAvailableTags() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0Avt7ejriwlxudGZfV2xJUGJZLXktm2RhQU1uRUgtaXc");
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Options");
  var data = s.getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = 1; // number of header rows to skip at top
  var tagColumn = 0; // column # (0-based) containing tag

  var availableTags = [];
  for (var row=headers; row < data.length; row++) {
    availableTags.push(data[row][tagColumn]);
  }

  return( availableTags );
}
```

In my Google Spreadsheet I also have a column with **image URLs that I would like to display in each autocomplete suggestion**. Here is a snippet with an example of what I'm trying to achieve. Is there any way to modify these two codes to make sure that **image URLs are being pulled from the same Google Spreadsheet**?

```js
$(function() {

      $(".search").autocomplete({
        source: //"autocomplete.php",
        [
          {id:"John Doe",
           value:"John Doe",
           label:"John Doe",
           img:"https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQGIx0cvucwTL1pstrlX_m5eIurp-bFAVnvBQ&usqp=CAU"},
          {id:"system Admin",
           value:"system Admin",
           label:"system Admin",
           img:"http://www.ericom.com/imgs/braftonArticles/3-things-every-system-admin-should-know-about-virtualization_16001411_800906167_0_14057272_500.jpg"}
        ],
        minLength: 1,
        select: function(event, ui) {
          /*
          var url = ui.item.id;
          if(url != '') {
            location.href = '...' + url;
          }
          */
        },
        html: true, 
        open: function(event, ui) {
          $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);

        }
      })
        .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li><div><img src='"+item.img+"'><span>"+item.value+"</span></div></li>" ).appendTo( ul );
      };

    });
```

```css
.ui-menu img{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  margin:0 5px 0 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="search"><br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values and the URLs of images from the Spreadsheet, and want to use them with `autocomplete`.

  - Your goal can be seen at the bottom script in your question.
- The values and URLs are in the columns "A" and "B".

### Modification points:

- In this case, it is required to retrieve the URLs and create an object for using with `autocomplete`.

  - It's like `[{id: value, value: value, label: value, img: url},,,]`.
  - So in your script, Google Apps Script and Javascript are required to be modified.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

#### HTML & Javascript side:

From:

```
function buildTagList(availableTags) {
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
}
```

To:

```
function buildTagList(availableTags) {
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  })
  .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li><div><img src='"+item.img+"'><span>"+item.value+"</span></div></li>" ).appendTo( ul );
  };
}
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

From:

```
for (var row=headers; row < data.length; row++) {
  availableTags.push(data[row][tagColumn]);
}
```

To:

```
for (var row=headers; row < data.length; row++) {
  var value = data[row][tagColumn];
  var url = data[row][tagColumn + 1];  // In this modification, it supposes that URLs are put in the column "B".
  availableTags.push({id: value, value: value, label: value, img: url});
}
```

### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that URLs are put in the column "B". If your actual situation is different from this, please modify the script.